# how to make game like monster run in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, levelhelper

hi iam new on game development can any one guide me how can i make the game like [Monsters, Inc. Run](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monsters-inc.-run/id555724449?mt=8).type game using level helper or any tutorial or software which you can guide me about this. Till now i just saw the toturial about level helper in which just shows righttoleft,lefttoright,uptodown,downtoup but i didn't find any tutorial or any thing in which player move right to left but also up and down when player change postion like in this game so can any one tell me here is the video link of the game too http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTSZOKQUk7Q.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn iOS development with `COCOS2D` and `BOX2D`. You can check one iOS game that i have worked in cocos2d.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30gHSRUU384
```

But in your scenario you have to make complete map first. Some softwares are available for MAC. Then You have to learn one joyStick example with which you can handle your player. The movement of player will be dependent on `JOYSTICK`. `JOYSTICK` example is available on GitHub also.`This link will help you.`

```
https://github.com/cjhanson/SneakyJoystick
```

Adding the Map to the Scene. means creation of whole map. You can see this tutorial.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjduXkenf4w
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 for being welcoming.

Comment: thanks for this help but i know about the cocos2d and box2d but i am stuck on the part of moving the scene on the player movement did you check the video which i shared ? and there is no control required so no need of any joystick

Comment: ok so what is the issue?

Comment: basically i developed the game using levelhelper and made the scene of 1600*580 half is sky and half is world my player can fly and go to the sky using this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/28713/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-latest-levelhelper-spritehelper-cocos2d-edition-part-1 in this tutorial user can only move lefttoright,righttoleft,uptodown,downtown but i made little change in this tutorial and made the scene in verticle position too so now scene is only showing sky i am unable to move it to the downword